# why my rabbitmq cluster connections and channels stay in flow status

Tags: rabbitmq

I am testing my rabbitmq 3 nodes cluster these days,
I use the java tool to test,

```
[root@server-42 bin ]$ ./runjava  com.rabbitmq.perf.PerfTest -x1 -y1 -e testex -Hmqp://username:password@123.123.123.2/test' -t topic -k sample.info -s 1500 -i 20
id: test-154506-639, starting consumer #0
id: test-154506-639, starting consumer #0, channel #0
id: test-154506-639, starting producer #0
id: test-154506-639, starting producer #0, channel #0
id: test-154506-639, time: 20.000s, sent: 8913 msg/s, received: 8804 msg/s, min/avg/max latency: 6317/251907/727492 microseconds
id: test-154506-639, time: 40.004s, sent: 8993 msg/s, received: 8991 msg/s, min/avg/max latency: 157294/256691/387926 microseconds
id: test-154506-639, time: 60.011s, sent: 9029 msg/s, received: 9019 msg/s, min/avg/max latency: 146744/255631/384696 microseconds
id: test-154506-639, time: 80.017s, sent: 8946 msg/s, received: 8972 msg/s, min/avg/max latency: 164969/259147/723908 microseconds
id: test-154506-639, time: 100.019s, sent: 8971 msg/s, received: 8949 msg/s, min/avg/max latency: 164012/258115/353767 microseconds
```

I find my rabbitmq  connection and channel status keeps at flow status.
however why is it ? is there any way to increase the performance?

I thought the flow status to keep the publisher to send messages to quick, in case that server can not queue the messages.

but the sending rate I used to test seems not high at all, why they are still in flow status?

anyone can help? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flow Control](https://www.rabbitmq.com/flow-control.html):

RabbitMQ will reduce the speed of connections which are publishing too quickly for queues to keep up.

If you want to learn more about the credit flow you can read this [doc](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/10/06/new-credit-flow-settings-on-rabbitmq-3-5-5/), in particular:

> To see how credit_flow and its settings affect publishing, let’s see how internal messages flow in RabbitMQ. Keep in mind that RabbitMQ is implemented in Erlang, where processes communicate by sending messages to each other.

you can try to increase `credit_flow` parameter

Comment: Thank you Gabriele,

Comment: Thank you Gabriele. I read the doc link, but I am have something not clear. 

Let's assume rabbitmq set credit_flow_default_credit by defalut InitialCredit is set to 200 by default, and MoreCreditAfter is set to 50, then it comes up a channel with 2 queues (q1 and q2), so that channel will be initiate 200 * 2 credit? is that right? and if each queue delivered 50 messages, it will return 50 credit to the channel, does not is ?

Comment: Let's assume q1 is very slow and can not return any credit to the channel any more, but q2 is quick enough to returns credit rapidly. so that the q2 will be able to grant credit to the channel, and that channel wont be blocked right?

Therefore, can I say that, if a connection has multiple channels (or a channel have multiple queues), it is less likely to block the connection or the channel (because if one channel or queue is faster, it is able to grant credits to upstream).

Comment: if you want learn more about internals read this https://github.com/rabbitmq/internals/blob/master/deliver_to_queues.md

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I was getting this due to Lack of memory (Too many unacked messages causes memory to be full which makes the connection in flow state)